# When will the support end for SLES 9.4?

Tags: sles

I just can't find any description when will the support end for SLES 9.4?

**QUESTION**: can someone point me to an URL/anything that says that SLES 9.4 support will end on XXXX.XX.XX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://support.novell.com/lifecycle/ the general support ended already while the extended support is until 31.08.2014:

[image: SLES 9.4 lifecycle]